# Simplify raster values in terra to category

Tags: r, gis, raster, terra

I have a large raster with many unique values and a complex attribute table. I would like to create a much simpler raster that only has the values of one level, a level which only has values 0-2.

Say I have a raster, but am really only interested in the variable `y`:

```
library(terra)

r <- rast(nrows=3, ncols=3)
values(r) <- 1:9

y_table <- data.frame(id=1:9, y=c(0,0,1,0,1,1,2,2,2))
levels(r) <- y_table
```

Is there a way to create a new raster that effectively substitutes the `y` level for the values? So rather than

```
levels(r)
  id y
1  1 0
2  2 0
3  3 1
4  4 0
5  5 1
6  6 1
7  7 2
8  8 2
9  9 2

values(r)
      y
 [1,] 1
 [2,] 2
 [3,] 3
 [4,] 4
 [5,] 5
 [6,] 6
 [7,] 7
 [8,] 8
 [9,] 9
```

I get to

```
levels(r_converted)
[1] ""

values(r_converted)
      lyr.1
 [1,]     0
 [2,]     0
 [3,]     1
 [4,]     0
 [5,]     1
 [6,]     1
 [7,]     2
 [8,]     2
 [9,]     2
```

I clumsily have tried both `classify` and `subst`:

```
testc <- classify(r, rcl=matrix(c(0:2, 0:2), ncol=2), right=NA)
tests <- subst(r, 0:2, 0:2)
```

but neither changes the values themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Use your data.frame as clasifification matrix, like:

```r
r <- terra::rast(nrows=3, ncols=3)
terra::values(r) <- 1:9

terra::plot(r)
```

[image]

```r
y_table <- data.frame(id=1:9, y=c(0,0,1,0,1,1,2,2,2))

s <- terra::classify(r, y_table)
terra::plot(s)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-03-13 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to synthesize the two answers to make it easier to solve the problem.

In the code in question, you are using the `levels` function to set the level of `r`. This does convert `r` to `factor` but this does not change the `value` of `r`.

```
is.factor(r)
[1] TRUE
values(r)
      y
 [1,] 1
 [2,] 2
 [3,] 3
 [4,] 4
 [5,] 5
 [6,] 6
 [7,] 7
 [8,] 8
 [9,] 9
```

I would recommend you use the `classify` function, which can handle large rasters better compared to `values`. However, it is important to note that the classified `r` will not be a `factor`, and you can use the `as.factor` function to convert it to a `factor` type.

```
r <- classify(r, y_table)
is.factor(r)
[1] FALSE

r <- as.factor(r)
is.factor(r)
[1] TRUE

levels(r)
  ID lyr.1
1  0     0
2  1     1
3  2     2

names(r) <- "y"
values(r)
      y
 [1,] 0
 [2,] 0
 [3,] 1
 [4,] 0
 [5,] 1
 [6,] 1
 [7,] 2
 [8,] 2
 [9,] 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Using r and r2, y_table and y_table2, but think this is what you're after:

```
 r <- rast(nrows=3, ncols=3)
values(r) <- 1:9
y_table <- data.frame(id=1:9, y=c(0,0,1,0,1,1,2,2,2))

r2 = r
y_table2 <- data.frame(id=1:9, y=c(0,0,1,0,1,1,2,2,2))
y_table2$y <- as.factor(y_table2$y)
values(r2) = y_table2$y
r2
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 3, 3, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 120, 60  (x, y)
extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (CRS84) (OGC:CRS84) 
source(s)   : memory
categories  : label 
name        : lyr.1 
min value   :     0 
max value   :     2

is.factor(r2)
[1] TRUE
is.factor(r)
[1] FALSE
```

see `?terra::factors` and your categories become multidimensional, your df has move than 2 columns.

Edit. I think both @grzegorz-sapjaszko and @geoffery both serve you better in advising `classify` as your rasters are likely far larger than your reprex. You don't say above that you 'need' factors and it seems more a way of simplifiying. This could readily be achieved by preparing a 'from-to' matrix that represents your many classes. So a bigger raster and classify

```
r9k = disagg(r, 9000, filename = 'terra_sof_78154418.tif')
rclmtx = matrix(c(1,0,2,0,3,1,4,0,5,1,6,1,7,2,8,2,9,2), nrow = 9, byrow = TRUE)
rclmtx
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1    0
 [2,]    2    0
 [3,]    3    1
 [4,]    4    0
 [5,]    5    1
 [6,]    6    1
 [7,]    7    2
 [8,]    8    2
 [9,]    9    2
r9k_cl = classify(r9k, rcl=rclmtx, filename = 'terra_rcl_r9k_sof_78154418.tif')
r9k_cl
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 27000, 27000, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 0.01333333, 0.006666667  (x, y)
extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (CRS84) (OGC:CRS84) 
source      : terra_rcl_r9k_sof_78154418.tif 
name        : lyr.1 
min value   :     0 
max value   :     2
```

It really comes down to your data and needs. If you already have `factors` you'd use `terra::subst`.